# How to extend Jmeter Http Sampler to inject auth token in request?

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

My requirement is I need to pick two http headers and few json fields in request body and using those values generate a auth token using Base64 encryption and set the auth Token into request body before Jmeter makes the HTTP request to the server.

How to do this in JMeter??

I tried creating custom functions in JMeter but in the Function class current Sampler object is null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) is what you're looking for

- Access request headers:

  ```
  sampler.getHeaderManager().get(0); // first header
  sampler.getHeaderManager().get(1); // second header
  ```
- Access request body:

  ```
  sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
  ```
- Base64 Encode something:

  ```
  import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.Base64Encoder;
  String encoded = Base64Encoder.encode("source");
  ```

For more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter see [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.